# Can we develop a .exe file, in c# for macros to set up excel file in new machine which does not contains any macros earlier

Tags: c#, excel, vba, windows

I need to develop an .exe file whenever we clicks on it should copy Personal.XLSB and Excel customization from one folder to XLSTART folder in perticular machine(i have done with this).And check the checkbox of developer tab and import of Excel customization through c# code. is it possible?help please.

Done with the files copy from one place to another.Now i have to do is import of Excel customization file and check checkbox of Developers tab in excel option. is this possible through c# code?

Answer (score 0):

Well, an EXE file is created as long as you build the project. So...BUILD->Batch Build And activate the "build" checkbox in the release configuration.  When you click the build button, the exe with some dependencies will be generated.  You can find this file on the debug folder of you project.

```
C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ProjectName\bin\Debug
```

Here is the code.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; 

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

            if (xlApp == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Excel is not properly installed!!");
                return;
            }


            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "ID";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Name";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 1] = "1";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 2] = "One";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 1] = "2";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 2] = "Two";



            xlWorkBook.SaveAs("d:\\csharp-Excel.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
            xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            xlApp.Quit();

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);

            MessageBox.Show("Excel file created , you can find the file d:\\csharp-Excel.xls");
        }

    }
}
```

Also, see the link below.

http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-create-excel.htm